# System for keeping track of user favorites

Tags: php, system, favorites

On my website, I have a table `movies` and a table `users`

I'm trying to have an "Add to favs" button that a user can click, which will add that movie to his favorites (ajax / javascript not necessary at the moment, just php).

So what's the simplest way I could do something like that? I've thought about this but I can't seem to find a solution (all I think of is way too complicated, and in my opinion not possible).

What's your thoughts?

I don't need a ready-made script, just an idea that could get me working (although if you have an example of such script, I'd be happy to look at it).

Thanks!

Comment: By favourites do you mean the user's bookmarks? If so, you might have to use Javascript.

Comment: No, he means a user-to-movies bookmarks list on the user account on the server with MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a third table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_favorites (
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  movie_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, movie_id),
  FOREIGN KEY user_id REFERENCES users (user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY movie_id REFERENCES movies (movie_id)
)
```

This is called an *intersection table* or *join table*, as it joins rows in the `users` table to rows in the `movies` table (as you see, each column is a foreign key). It is also defines a *many-to-many* relationship, because one user can like many movies and one movie can be liked by many users.

When you go to add a favorite movie for a user, all you have to do is insert a row in this table with the ID of the user and the ID of the movie:

```
INSERT INTO user_favorites(user_id, movie_id) VALUES([user ID], [movie ID])
```

To see what movies a user has favorited:

```
SELECT movie_id FROM user_favorites WHERE user_id = [user ID]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, as I said above it's the same thing basically, but I'm taking it in consideration, so thank you!

Comment: Just a small question now, how would I go on with posting this into the database, I have no clue why, usually I'm able to do that, but now my "Add to favorite" would be a link instead of a form button, so whats the best way to call the SQL statement?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure why it would matter if it was a link or a button. On the target page, just prepare your `INSERT` query and execute it. Am I missing what you're asking?

Answer (score 12):

This is a many-to-many relationship.  A user can favorite many movies, and a movie can be favored by many users.  In an RDBMS, you represent a many-to-many relationship with a third table.  I call this an *intersection table* but it goes by other names too.

Create a table with two columns.  The columns are both foreign keys, referencing movies and users, respectively.

```
CREATE TABLE Favorites (
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  movie_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, movie_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES Movies(movie_id)
);
```

When a user chooses to favorite a movie:

```
INSERT INTO Favorites (user_id, movie_id) VALUES (?, ?)
```

When a user decides they don't like a movie any longer, delete the corresponding row:

```
DELETE FROM Favorites WHERE (user_id, movie_id) = (?, ?)
```

To get the set of movies favored by a given user:

```
SELECT movie_id FROM Favorites WHERE user_id = ?
```

To get the set of users who favor a given movie:

```
SELECT user_id FROM Favorites WHERE movie_id = ?
```

---

Regarding one of your comments:

You shouldn't make the "Add to favorite" a link.  Indexers like Google will follow links, and then before you know it, every user has favorited every movie.

The general best practice is that read-only operations can be GET requests, while operations that write to the database can be POST requests.  This means that you need to use a `<form>` element to submit POST requests, not an `<a href="...">` element.

Comment: Alright, perfect answer, very detailed, I will be trying this right now!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a new table:

```
user_favorite_movies
--------------------
ID (primary key)
userID (foreign key)
movieID (foreign key)
date
```

Then when the user clicks the 'Add Favorite' button, you just insert a new row into user_favorite_movies with the users ID from the user table, the movie id from the movie table, and the date it was added (good for sorting later).

Hope this helps!

Best,

-Eric

Comment: Thanks alot Eric for your answer, looks like the one above, but still very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table `favourites` with three columns, `id`, `mid` and `uid`. To add a favourite:

```
INSERT INTO favourites (mid, uid) VALUES (3, 5)
```

To search for favourites of one user:

```
SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE uid = 7
```

To search for people who favourited one movie:

```
SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE mid = 9
```

Comment: Thanks Delan, very appreciated as stated in above answers! Although it's also the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can see, you'll still need to use JavaScript or Ajax to do the post, unless you want to refresh the page every time thet mark/unmark a favorite, and also to add/remove  the new favorite indicator in place at the same time.

Or am I missing something?