# how can posible like this format query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have a database that has a bunch of records like this.

tbl_friends in four entry.

########## #################

## id   - user_id-------friends------

1   ------      11        -------  --------------  2,3,40,5,6,7,89,10
 2  ------    2       --------------------- 1,3,4,5,67,89,50

3  ---- - 3     --------------------- 1,2,54,6,7,8,78

4   ---- - 40   -----------------------12,2,3,34,5,6,6,11

I want Run query column name 'user_id '11 to remove 'friends' column 40  and like this  format   ' 2,3,5,6,7,89,10' and user_id 40 remove 11  view in data base table like this format
'12,2,3,34,5,6,6,11' how to replace query is actually going to be working inside the string, whats doing its pattern matching is unfriend to improve any performance - it is actually going to generate  work query for like.

like this image view query
[image]

please help me.
thanks

Comment: It is very bad idea to save foreign keys as csv

Comment: You should change your database design,  have a table with ID ,  user ID and friendid,  then each row is one user has one friend. This way you can delete records accurately without impacting performance, although if you have a huge number of users you. May need a lot of storage

Comment: If you're using mySQL 5.7+ you should use the JSON type if you insist on this approach, however I'd recommend rethinking how you're doing this anyway. A join table that joined a friend to another friend would be a much tidier solution.

Comment: I edit my question like as image view  query format please help this

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

if the user deleted his account or you decided to delete him or you changed his id it's going to be hard to remove him from each and every one who is friend with him

you should use foreign keys and define a many to many relationship here is some great answers about that.

[System for keeping track of user favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722242/system-for-keeping-track-of-user-favorites)

Comment: I many particular flowing like Image to explain than same is run query use and delete user_id 11 remove friends 40 and someone  as its same than user_id 40 remove fried 11 . how can query like image ?

Answer (score 0):

```
like this 

<?php
include('confi.php');
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
 if (isset($_POST['user_id']) && isset($_POST['friend_id'])) {
    $user_id    = $_POST['user_id'];
    $friend_id  = $_POST['friend_id'];
    $sql1       = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_friends WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    $sql_chack  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_friend_request WHERE `user_id`='$user_id' AND `friend_id`='$friend_id' OR `user_id`='$friend_id' AND`friend_id`='$user_id'");
    $sql2       = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_friends WHERE user_id='$friend_id'");
    $results1   = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
    $myString   = $results1['friends'];
    $results2   = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
    $myString2  = $results2['friends'];
    $myArray    = explode(',', $myString);
    $myArray2   = explode(',', $myString2);
    $del_val    = $friend_id;
    $del_val2   = $user_id;
    $to_remove  = explode(',', $del_val);
    $to_remove2 = explode(',', $del_val2);
    $result     = array_diff($myArray, $to_remove);
    $result2    = array_diff($myArray2, $to_remove2);
    $string     = implode(',', $result);
    $string2    = implode(',', $result2);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql_chack)) {
        /* echo $string.'<br>';
        echo $string2.'<br>'; */
        $sql_friend_user    = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tbl_friends SET friends='$string' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
        $sql_friends_friend = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE tbl_friends SET friends='$string2' WHERE user_id='$friend_id'");
        $sql_recent         = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `tbl_recent` WHERE `user_id`='$user_id' AND `friend_id`='$friend_id' OR `user_id`='$friend_id' AND`friend_id`='$user_id'");
        $sql_friend         = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `tbl_friend_request`  WHERE `user_id`='$user_id' AND `friend_id`='$friend_id' OR `user_id`='$friend_id' AND`friend_id`='$user_id'");
        $json               = array(
            "status" => 1,
            "msg" => "success"
        );
    } else {
        $json = array(
            "status" => 0
        );
    }

} else {
    $json = array(
        "status" => 0000
    );
}

 } else {
$json = array(
    "status" => 0,
    "msg" => "Request Method not accepted !"
);
 }
     mysqli_close($conn);
   header('Content-type: application/json');
      echo json_encode($json);
     ?>
```